# Connecting to a same signal in two windows

Tags: c++, qt

Can you think of a reason why this second scenario not working?

I have signal connection in two windows , `Settings` and `Patients`

In `Settings`:

```
Settings::Settings( QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Settings)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

connect(&api, &tetra_grip_api::tetraGripEvent,this, &Settings::eventHandler);
...
}
```

`api` is global instance of a class.

And in `Patients`:

```
Patients::Patients( QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Patients)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

connect(&api, &tetra_grip_api::tetraGripEvent,this, &Patients::eventHandlerTwo);

}
```

**Situation1 - Working**

I construct both `Settings` and `Patients` window from `Main`

```
#include <QApplication>

tetra_grip_api api;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    api.openSerialPort();
    QObject::connect(api.serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()), &api, SLOT(readData()));


    Settings  w(nullptr); //---->this behaves right
    Patients  v(nullptr); //---- >this behaves right

    v.show();
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

By working I mean , both the slots are being called , and `QLabel` set text accordingly

**Situation 2 - Not working**

I call `Patients` from `Settings`:

```
void Settings::on_pushButton_patients_clicked()
{
    this->close();
    stagetwo = new Patients(this);
    stagetwo -> show();
}
```

where `stagetwo` is public

```
public:
     Settings(QString,QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Settings();
     Patients *stagetwo;
```

Here `Settings` works just fine (slot being called) but `Patients::eventhandlerTwo` is not being called at all.

**EDIT (Found the bug)**

It's bit late to understand that I need to call a method in the API (`battery_percentage`) to emit signal `tetraGripEvent` ( `bettery_percentage` will contact "battery register" in the device and this will force API to emit signal)

basically I need to do this on both `Settings` and `Patients`

```
#include "settings.h"
#include "ui_settings.h"

 Settings ::   Settings (QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Settings )
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(&api, &tetra_grip_api::tetraGripEvent,this, &Settings::eventHandler);
...
  tetra_grip_api::battery_percentage(); ------> calling this only emit the signal

}
```

and in `Patients`

```
#include "patients.h"
#include "ui_patients.h"

Patients::Patients(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Patients)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


  connect(&api, &tetra_grip_api::tetraGripEvent,this, &Patients::eventHandlerTwo);
...
  tetra_grip_api::battery_percentage(); 

}
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Does your `Settings` type have the [`Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) attribute set?

Comment: Look here:
https://github.com/bialasjaroslaw/event_handlers
If you click button and open second window both Events are handled, because object of class Patients is created. If you do not click within 5 second (event is timeout from QTimer), Patients object will not be created, though never connected to event signal. Basically there is no object of class Patients connected to QTimer::timeout, so nothings except Settings::eventHandler is fired.
In your first example both objects are created just at the begining, so there are connected from the start.

Answer (score 2):

As per Qt documentation for [`QWidget::close()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#close), which [`QMainWindow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html) is being inherited from:

> The `QApplication::lastWindowClosed()` signal is emitted when the last
>   visible primary window (i.e. window with no parent) with the
>   **`Qt::WA_QuitOnClose` attribute** set is closed. ***By default this attribute
>   is set for all widgets except transient windows*** such as splash
>   screens, tool windows, and popup menus.

So, in the second scenario, when you set the parent of `Patients` to a `Settings` instance, you should expect an undefined behavior like this. Because by calling `Settings::close()` should delete `Settings` and quit the application when the call returns to the event loop. You can explicitly change it by :

```
Settings::Settings( QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Settings)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, false);
    connect(&api, &tetra_grip_api::tetraGripEvent,this, &Settings::eventHandler);
...
}
```

You can also reparent both windows to another window.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  `this->setWindowFlag(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, false);`  throws an erros saying  `error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'Qt::WindowType' with an rvalue of type 'Qt::WidgetAttribute'
qwidget.h:569:38: note: passing argument to parameter here`